# Erlang: which pattern matching is more efficient (lists)?

Tags: list, erlang, pattern-matching, cons

I'm going through "Pragmatic Programming Erlang" where there is a function defined like this:

```
split("\r\n\r\n" ++ T, L) -> {reverse(L), T};
split([H|T], L) -> split(T, [H|L]);
split([], _) -> more.
```

What interests me is first match, namely `"\r\n\r\n" ++ T` - is there performance difference between such a pattern and similar one, that I came up with: `[13,10,13,10|T]`? Or are they equivalent?

I know it's very simple question and that I could (probably) check it myself, but *if* there is a difference, I'd like to know why that is the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"\r\n\r\n" ++ T` is just syntax sugar for `[13,10,13,10|T]`. It should perform same. If not there is something wrong ;-)

Comment: I thought maybe `L1 ++ L2` is somehow different, because I couldn't find a way to transform it to `cons`es when used like that: `T ++ "\r\n"` - but thanks to your answer I thought again and I realized that it is possible, although somewhat lengthy. Thanks!

Comment: `T ++ "\r\n"` can't be transformed to conses so can't be used in pattern match.